I cannot obtain the third access token required for using the Instagram Graph API
I want to verify what kind of data can be obtained using the Instagram Graph API, but I cannot obtain the necessary third access token. Although I can obtain the second token, when attempting to obtain the third token, an empty JSON is returned.
Here are the steps I have already tried. If there are any mistakes or if you know the correct way, could you please let me know?

Switching to an Instagram professional account
Creating a Facebook page
Linking the Facebook page and Instagram professional account
Creating a Facebook app in Meta For Developers
Obtaining the first access token with Graph API Explorer
Using the first access token to obtain the second access token from the following URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=%5BAppID%5D&client_secret=%5BAppSecret%5D&fb_exchange_token=%5BFirstAccessToken%5D


Obtaining the ID from the following URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/me?access_token=%5BSecondAccessToken%5D


When attempting to obtain the third access token from the following URL, only an empty JSON with "data" is returned:

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/%5BID%5D/accounts?access_token=%5BSecondAccessToken%5D



enter image description here

"Obtaining the ID from the following URL" - that step is superfluous, you can still use me instead of an id for the next request. "only an empty JSON with "data" is returned" - then your access token either doesn't include the necessary permission to view a user's pages; or you did not select the relevant pages when granting the permission.

For the last step, when you're trying to access the Facebook pages connected to your account, remember that specific permissions are necessary.
So during the login process, ensure you include the "pages_show_list" permission in the scope. This will enable you to access the list of pages using the access token generated after login.
